# How to add an SVG to a PDF using iText7 without rasterizing

Tags: svg, itext7

I need to add an SVG image to a PDF, but **not** as a rasterized image. This was possible in iText5 - however, I have been unable to figure out the corresponding procedure in iText7. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David,

SVG, at this point, isn't supported by iText.
We are currently investigating and estimating the required work to add SVG support to iText7.
We expect to have a minimal working prototype near the end of the first quarter of 2018.
This is an estimate, I cannot make any binding promises about this.

It is true that (a small amount of) SVG support was available in iText5.
However, this way of rendering SVG files was suboptimal and only worked for very basic files.

Comment: Today, 27 April 2018, iText 7.1.2 will be released, which has (experimental) SVG support. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059456/how-to-add-an-svg-to-a-pdf-using-itext7#comment87135728_50059456