# SVG graphics are not well drawn in pdf by iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, itext7

This code a use to draw SVG graphic in pdf by iText7.1.4:

```
public const String SVG = @"C:\Users\Desktop\spectrumled_logo.svg";
string enc_text = File.ReadAllText(SVG);                            
SvgConverter.DrawOnCanvas(enc_text, pdfCanvas);
```

This is a **SVG graphic**, link below:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sDdt8joT2wlwLQtlcp2XYA81I06t34qN

But the result of inserting SVG into pdf is not satisfactory, link below:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eha5qT3AJFu6JbjdW03WKq_50aG0E7T_

Why iText draws the graphic in pdf doc in that way, where is the problem?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059456/how-to-add-an-svg-to-a-pdf-using-itext7

Comment: Please use the latest iText version. I've converted your svg file with the 7.1.6-SANPSHOT and the resultant file seems to be quite satisfactory