# Embed svg image to PDF file in C#

Tags: snap.svg, svg-animate, svg.js, jquery-svg

How can we add svg file to a pdf file proramatically using c# or Js

Should not use any third party library

Comment: Please read: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059456/how-to-add-an-svg-to-a-pdf-using-itext7